# Convert XWD to PNG via command line on Windows

Tags: imagemagick, gimp, image-conversion

I have a script that generates an XWD file which needs to be converted to a PNG file.
When attempting to convert this with ImageMagick, I get the following output. I've found the delegate download site for ImageMagick, however it doesn't appear to have anything for XWD, much less anything for Windows.

[image]

I have also tried using the GIMP command line, however I cannot find any solid reference for converting via GIMP on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer [Nconvert from XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/), because no installation is necessary on Windows.

Command line is easy to use:

```
nconvert.exe -out png input.xwd
```

Answer (score 0):

The [XWD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xwd) format is apart of the X11 sub-system. I believe the windows binary package ships with a bare-bone X library `xlib/X11/XWDFile.h`. You can verify your local IM install by running the following:

```sh
identify -list configure
```

Find the line that starts with **DELEGATES**, and look for **x** in the list. Example:

```
DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lcms png ps tiff x xml zlib
```

If **x** is not present, try re-installing [ImageMagick for Windows](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/windows/) from [source](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/install.html), or evaluate the article *[Use From Another Package or Program](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/windows.html)* for binary-package installs.